# DB2 JDBC query that works for update does not work for batchUpdate

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, db2, zos

I am trying to implement batch updates in a program, and I think I might be running into a bug in the DB2 jdbc drivers or something. Here is my query:

`insert into CONTENTSOURCE (CONTENTSOURCE_ID, CS_NAME) values (?, ENCRYPT(CAST(? as VARCHAR(280) FOR BIT DATA)))`

The following is my call to a spring `JdbcTemplate` for a single insert, which works.

```
query = QUERY_INSERT_ENCRYPT;
insert.update(
                query,
                new Object[] {
                        contentSourceId,
                        contentSourceObject.getContentSourceName()
                                .getBytes() });
```

But when I attempt the same in batch, I get an error that does not appear to apply to my query.

```
insertArgs.add(new Object[] { contentSource.getContentSourceId(),
                contentSource.getContentSourceName().getBytes() });
returnArray = batchInsert.batchUpdate(QUERY_INSERT_ENCRYPT, insertArgs);
```

When running the batchUpdate, every row gets a SQLCODE -312, but I am not doing anything with variables. Here is some of the output of the errors scraped from the exception.

```
Server error message: A NON-ATOMIC INSERT STATEMENT ATTEMPTED TO PROCESS MULTIPLE ROWS OF DATA, BUT ERRORS OCCURRED

--------------- SQLCA ---------------

Error code: -254

SQLERRMC: INSERT

  token 0: INSERT

SQLERRP: DSNXRINS

SQLERRD(1): -400

SQLERRD(2): 0

SQLERRD(3): 0

SQLERRD(4): -1

SQLERRD(5): 0

SQLERRD(6): 0

SQLSTATE: 22530

Server error message: VARIABLE <unknown> IS NOT DEFINED OR NOT USABLE

--------------- SQLCA ---------------

Error code: -312

SQLERRMC: <unknown>

  token 0: <unknown>

SQLERRP: DSNXRIHS

SQLERRD(1): -996

SQLERRD(2): 0

SQLERRD(3): 0

SQLERRD(4): -1

SQLERRD(5): 0

SQLERRD(6): 0

SQLSTATE: 42618
```

I found a bugfix for a different level/version of the driver from a long time ago, so I'm confused whether or not this is the same problem or not.
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=isg1PK85150#more
Relevant excerpt:

> All Connectivity: A SQLCODE312 (-312) with
>   "SqlSyntaxErrorException: VARIABLE  IS NOT DEFINED
>   OR NOT USABLE" was reported when running PureQuery client
>   optimizer on a static execution mode connection to DB2 z/OS
>   Version 8 or above. The problem was related to the
>   Multi-Row Insert (MRI) support that the driver uses to
>   implement executeBatch() when connecting to DB2 z/OS
>   version 8 or above. In this case, statements were bound
>   without MRI for dynamic execution mode but were
>   incorrectly executed with MRI format for static
>   execution mode. (115716)

So, am I doing something wrong, or is it likely something is going wrong in the driver, and I should open an issue with IBM?

Comment: Looks like one of your variables is longer than 280 chars or perhaps it can't be interpreted using the getBytes method (which uses the default charset). This would explain the  'variable is not defined or usable' error. The fact that you're getting -312 for every row might suggest that nothing has actually been commited (everything's been rollbacked). This might be driver/database dependent (take a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeBatch())

Comment: At this point, I am only using test data, all of which is happy path values because the batch update has yet to work.

If I'm not mistaken, -312 is regarding a variable defined in SQL, which the SQL I'm using is completely unrelated. This also doesn't explain why the exact same data using the exact same SQL can be inserted on a row-by-row basis, but fails in a batch.

Comment: I can  only say: try with a small batch (only 2 inserts) and gradually increase the number of inserts. This way, hopefully, you'll be able to eliminate some  of the problems.

Comment: I have tried 1, 2, and 3 rows at a time in my testing, every single row has the same sqlcode -312, and every row's data has been successfully validated against using the JdbcTemplate update method before using the JdbcTemplate batchUpdate method. I don't see any alternative other than there's a bug in the driver itself.

Comment: Did you try the latest  driver?

Comment: Yes, I have tried using the latest driver, still same behavior.

Comment: If I find the time tomorrow, I'll try to do a batch insert against a DB2 9.7. database. I'll report the results here.

Comment: Well, it worked for me. I used a DB2 9.7 database and the driver was db2jcc.jar. I tried batch inserts as well as batch updates and had no problems with it. My code was plain JDBC (not Spring JDBCTemplate)

Comment: I also found this http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-jdbctemplate-batchupdate-example/